# want to display a table under each row of Jqgrid (row related information) similar to subgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I know how to use subgrid for jqgrid, but I want to display row detail information in a table.

Here the picture that elaborate my issue,

[image]

I have the above kind of grid, here I am looking for a hyperlink for "No Of Packet" column (or a side image near to 2, and so on.), when user click on that link (2) or image, I expected a drill down table instead of subgrid

Please suggest some help how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean with "table with fix number of columns"? All tables have fix number of columns. Could you formulate the requirement more clear. Probably an example or a picture would clear what you need.

Comment: @Oleg, I understand, it bit to difficult to understand my problem. I tried to show my problem with some picture, hope I am able to explain you. Thanks!

Comment: What you mean under "drill down table"? Is it some kind of popup windows (div) with the information in table format? Is it a row which will be inserted after the clicked row (like subgrid)?... Where is the source of the information which will be placed in the "drill down table"? Is an Ajax request need be sent to the server to get the information? Do you have already the required information locally? Where? You wrote before "want to display a table under each row". Is it mean that the information should be displayed in **all rows** immediately after the click on hyperlink from "No Of Packet"?

Comment: Sorry, but you should formulate the requirements unambiguously and to use better well know terminology.

Comment: @Oleg, this is like custom row detail which is look like subgrid and the source is a Ajax call to the server to get the detail. Initially when grid load, I don't want to load the custom row detail, on click of link/image will only show the detail, also I want expand/collapse facility?

Comment: I understand some terminology are wrong, SORRY!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66813/discussion-between-user2994834-and-oleg).

Comment: Sorry, but you still not clear all opened questions. Subgrid looks very close to your requirements. You can call `expandSubGridRow` hyperlink for "No Of Packet" column. The subgrid can be implemented as Subgrid as Grid. It can have `datatype: "json"` to load the data from the server. You can hide "subgrid" column to be mostly close to your picture, but it will be unclear for me how the user could collapce the subgrid.